# MySql Dump output conditional comments? Execute dump as query to restore database

Tags: mysql, comments, restore, dump

Note: Actually two questions...

When I dump a mysql database using the `mysqldump` binary I get a file that contains (among other lines) this:
`CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`MyDatabase`/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;`

I have searched on Google and MySql reference but I cant find what those /*!32312 mean, and how they work. I can only guess that they are conditional comments. Like e.g. if build > 32312, execute "IF NOT EXIST"?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

The reason my I want to know this, is because I am failing to execute a restore using the contents of the dump as 1 query in a C# client. Using this code:

```
            MySqlConnection msc = default(MySqlConnection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = default(MySqlCommand);
            MySqlTransaction mst = default(MySqlTransaction);
            try
            {
                //Create a connection to the database
                msc = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                msc.Open();

                //Creata a MySql Transaction
                mst = msc.BeginTransaction();

                cmd = msc.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Transaction = mst;
                cmd.CommandText = ContentsOfMySqlDumpSql;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                mst.Commit();
            }
```

Do I really have to start mysql as a process with commandline arguments to restore the dump? As I really want to accomplish the restore of the dump using it as a SQL Query in the C# client, as its more convenient than controlling the mysql binaries output and exit code and such...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are indeed version-specific comments, as explained in [Comment syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html).

These comments allow to execute optional parts of statements only if the server supports them.

```
/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

means this part will be executed only if the version of the MySQL server is 4.01.00 or higher.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I guess I was looking in the wrong direction. As it is perfectly explained in the URL you provided.

Answer (score 0):

*As stated by the original poster of the question :*

---

Using `Query = Regex.Replace(QueryOrFilePath, @"(?:\/\*!\d+\s)|(?:\*\/)", @"", RegexOptions.Multiline);` Will remove all comment-and-version-a-like notations and only keeps the query inside the version specific comment.

Useful if you are sure you are executing the query on a version compatible database.